# How to automaticaly resize view depending the mobile screen size

Tags: android, view, size, screen, cardview

Im trying to design a CardView to implement it in a RecyclerView whith a GridLayout. I designed the cardView but when I prove my design in different mobiles with different screen sizes the design doesn't scale itself. I used "dp" unity and "sp" unity like "Android developers" page shows.I don't know if I must create a design for each screen size or each screen density.

Can you help me?

Code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
app:cardElevation="4dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
android:id="@+id/dlvsr_CardView">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Text view tittle"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text view subtittle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here are the examples:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRpBY.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/scL7K.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrCyZ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/REzt7.png

Comment: Yes, unlesss I use 0 margins, the dp is useless when chaging to different screen sizes, it doesn't scale properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) library for **sp** and [this](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) for **dp** for all screen sizes. It has different dimen.xml with values respected to the different dpi.

This is the simplest solution to your problem.

Add all the ssp and sdp XML in your **res->values->** to your project and then in UI xml use them like below.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textEmailAddressInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp">
```

In above usage example you can see I have used **14ssp** as **android:textSize** and **10sdp** for **android:layout_marginTop** which will be adjusted according to the dpi of all screen, this will work for all mobile size, tablet and even with Android TV.

Please let me know if you need more info on this.

Comment: this two libraries work as I need, but trying some designs, when I change landscape to portrait or viceversa the resizing is not good for me. Maybe is better for that to create different layouts for each views(Landscape and Portrait)?

Comment: @ProRiderZ115 Yes you can create the layout-land folder for landscape layouts.

Comment: @ProRiderZ115 Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572496/different-layouts-for-horizontal-and-vertical-for-an-android-app

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to create different design for each screen size.
But at least you have to use different dimension for each screen.

To do that

1. You have to create Different values folder for different screens . Like

   ```
   values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi        
   values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi  

   values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi     
   values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi   

   values-xxhdpi           5.5"  1080x1920 xxhdpi    
   values-xxxhdpi           5.5" 1440x2560 xxxhdpi  

   values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi     
   values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi 

   values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi    
   values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi        

   values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi        

   values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi    
   values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
   values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
   ```
2. Create a new `dimens.xml` file by right clicking all the `values` folder and choosing **New > Values resource file**. Write `dimens` for the name. (You could also call it `dimen` or `dimensions`. The name doesn't really matter, only the `dimen` resource type that it will include.)
3. Add a `dimen` name and value.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <dimen name="my_value">16dp</dimen>
   </resources>
   ```

   Values can be in `dp`, `px`, or `sp`.
4. Use the value in xml

   ```
   <TextView
       android:padding="@dimen/my_value"
       ... />
   ```

   or in code

   ```
   float sizeInPixels = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.my_value);
   ```

Comment: How can I change de dimension for each screen size??

Comment: You have to create Different values folder for different screens. Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861248/4972317

Comment: But when i create that folders with the dimensions.xml inside, what is the way to attach the dimens for each size screen?

Comment: You don't have to worry about it. Android will do it for you.

Comment: Could you give an example please?

Comment: Android will automatically select different value folder for different screen size.

Comment: yes, but i don't know the way to create that folders correctly with proper names.I need that, Could you help? Maybe in a private chat if you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConstraintLayout instead of LinearLayout and constraints view vertically and horizontally. it will be compatible with the different screen sized automatically.